# ML5, sentiment analysis: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'the' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ml5.js

I am trying to assess sentiment of a book using `ML5 sentiment` api:

```
const sentiment = ml5.sentiment('movieReviews', modelReady)

// When the model is loaded
function modelReady() {
  // model is ready
  console.log("Model Loaded!");
}

// make the prediction
fetch('../../data/brothers.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    const prediction = sentiment.predict(text)
    console.log(prediction)
    createDiv('predicted sentiment - ' + prediction)
  })  

function setup() {
}
```

`text` is loaded fine, I can print it to the console. The following error happens on the line with the `predict` method:

[image]

If I substitute `text` with a single word, the error stays the same. So what am I doing wrong here, how to make things work?

Comment: Try adding `return` before `response.text()`. If you are chaining a promise, if you don't return anything then it calls the next `.then()` with `undefined`.

Comment: @dwosk not necessary

Comment: Ah you're right I see in the fetch documentation it has chaining setup the same way as OP

Comment: Are you sure that `predict` takes a string as its argument?

Comment: Perhaps you are calling `fetch` before the model is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the function is called **before** the model is loaded (as noted by *@dwosk* as well). Calls to `predict` must be done **after** the model is ready.

In other words, the function must be called at **A**, not at **B**:

```
function modelReady() {
  console.log("Model Loaded!");
  [A: THIS LOADS WHEN THE MODEL IS READY]
}

[B: THIS LOADS BEFORE THE MODEL IS READY]
```

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/RwaXjez?editors=1011

Please note that the `fetch` function is mocked to return "a beautiful happy cat" for simplicity.